# invalid initialization of non-const reference from an rvalue in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Most compilers [detect the error](http://ideone.com/3mbVEG) in the following code.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
};

Foo create_foo()
{
    return { 42 };
}

int main()
{
    Foo& my_foo = create_foo(); // This should trigger a compiler error.
    my_foo.i = 33; // Undefined behaviour!
}
```

Visual C++ 2015 on my machine does not. Is there a compiler flag / warning level or something that I can set to make VC2015 detect the error?

Comment: `Foo& my_foo = create_foo();` is wrong code

Comment: because `create_foo` returns an object, but `Foo&` requiretments a link to existing object

Comment: you shoud use `Foo my_foo = create_foo();`

Comment: @nikniknik2016 I know what is wrong. I want my compiler (VC2015) to detect it, because other compilers also detect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC has an extension that allows this, so by default, this is not an error. You can disable the extensions with the flag `/Za` or in your IDE via

> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see [How to: Open Project Property Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e79xc5h1.aspx).
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Configuration Properties, C/C++, Language.
> 3. Modify the Disable Language Extensions property.

(From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx))

Then, MSVC will try to follow the language standard.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are not getting a warning is because your **warning level** is not high enough, a **level 4** is required for that. MSVC will set it to 3 by default.

> > Property Pages => C/C++ => General => Warning Level: Level4 (/W4)

Or as pointed out by Baum mit Augen, disable extensions, altho this is not that simple if you are using headers like `<windows>`, as some of them use the extensions and you will get compile errors.

> > Property Pages => C/C++ => Language => Disable Language Extensions property: Yes (/Za)